# What does this assignment to a string literal do?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, string-literals, pointer-arithmetic

This is my code. I want to know what is happening here. Can anybody describe the code?

```
char *string;  
string = "Le Casa de Papel";      
*(str+1) = 'a';  
return 0;
```

Comment: The code has undefined behavior.:)

Comment: no one knows, `str` is undefined

Comment: Pokes the character `'a'` in a random memory location

Answer (score 4):

The code snippet has undefined behavior.

The programmer is trying to substitute the second character of the string literal `"Le Casa de Papel"` that is `'e'` for the character `'a'` using the pointer arithmetic.

```
char *string;  
string = "Le Casa de Papel";      
*(str+1) = 'a';
```

Note: I think there is a typo and the last statement shall be

```
*(string+1) = 'a';
```

that can be rewritten in other way to make it more clear like

```
string[1] = 'a';
```

But you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

To make the code valid you should substitute the declaration of the pointer that points to a string literal for an array declaration elements of which are initialized by the string literal as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char string[] = "Le Casa de Papel";
    
    puts( string );
    
    *(string + 1 ) = 'a'; 

    puts( string );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Le Casa de Papel
La Casa de Papel
```

Comment: "can you say what is the correct code and why does the code have undefined behavior?(what is happening in it?)"

Comment: @asd See my updated answer. As I wrote you may not change a string literal. Therefor the original code that tries to do that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `str` is supposed to be `string`, this code is attempting to change the second character in the string from `e` to `a`, changing `"Le Casa de Papel"` to `"La Casa de Papel"`.  The line

```
*(str+1) = 'a';
```

is equivalent to writing

```
str[1] = 'a';
```

The problem here is that `"Le Casa de Papel"` is a *string literal*, and attempting to modify the contents of a string literal leads to *undefined behavior*.  String literals are supposed to be immutable - trying to change the value of a string literal *should* be like trying to change the value of an integer constant, e.g., `1 = 2` - the operation is nonsensical.  However, unlike integer constants, string literals have to be stored in memory somewhere, and that memory may or may not be read-only. Attempting to change a string literal may lead to a runtime error, or it may work as expected, or something else may happen - the language definition doesn't require the compiler or runtime environment to handle it in any particular way.